# How to include input file name in output file name in ffmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, ffmpeg, gnu-parallel

I want to extract frames as images from video
and I want each image to be named
as `InputFileName_number.bmp`. 
How can I do this?

I tried the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i clip.mp4 fr1/$filename%d.jpg -hide_banner
```

but it is not working as I want. 
I want to get, for example, `clip_1.bmp`, but what I get is `1.bmp`.

I am trying to use it with GNU parallel to extract images of multiple videos and I am new to both so I want some king of dynamic file naming `input` -> `input_number.bmp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$filename` is handled as a shell variable.

What about

```
ffmpeg -i clip.mp4 fr1/clip_%d.jpg -hide_banner
```

or

```
$mp4filename=clip
ffmpeg -i ${mp4filename}.mp4 fr1/${mp4filename}_%d.jpg -hide_banner
```

?

**Update:** For use with gnu parallel, you can use parallel's `-i` option:

> -i
>   Normally the command is passed the argument at the end of its command line. With this option, any instances of "{}" in the command are replaced with the argument.

The resulting command line could be as simple as

```
parallel -i ffmpeg -i {} fr1/{}_%d.jpg -hide_banner -- *.mp4
```

if you can live with the extension in the output files.

Be aware that you may not actually want to run this in parallel on a traditional hard-disk as the concurrent i/o will slow it down.

**Edit:** Fixed variable reference as pointed out by @DonHolgo.

Comment: I am trying to use it with gnu parallel to extract images of multiple videos and I am new to both so I want some king of dynamic file naming inpu -> input_number.bmp

Comment: That should be `fr1/${mp4filename}_%d.jpg` in the second example so that the underscore is not considered part of the variable name.

Comment: @mark I extended my answer. In the future, please mention the full details in your question right from the beginning.